# How to use AWS Autoscaling Effectively

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Please lemme know the answer for below question:

In Reviewing the Auto scaling events for ur application you notice that application is scaling up and down multiple times in the same hour.What design you make to optimize for cost while preserving elasticity?

```
A.Modify Autoscaling group termination polict to terminate old Oldinstance    first
B..Modify Autoscaling group termination polict to terminate old new instance first
C.Modify Cloud watch alarm period that triggers Autoscaling down policy
D.Modify auto scaling group cool down timers.
E.Modify the Autoscaling policy to use scheduled scaling Actions.
```

im guessing D&E ..Please suggest!!

Comment: how many answers are allowed? I would not say E because it will not preserve elasticity. D seems reasonable.

Comment: So I would sayC & D.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a question from from the many "**Become AWS certified!**" websites. The purpose of such questions is to determine whether you understand AWS enough to be officially recognised via certification. If you are merely asking people for the correct answer, then you are only learning the answer... not the actual knowledge!

If you truly researched Auto Scaling and thought about it, here's some of the things you should be thinking about. I present this information hoping that you'll actually learn about AWS rather than just memorising answers (which won't help you in the real world).

**Scaling In/Out vs Up/Down**

Auto Scaling is all about **launching** additional Amazon EC2 instances when they are required (eg during times of peak load) and **terminating** them when they are no longer needed, thereby saving money.

Since instances are being added and removed, this is referred to as **Scaling Out** and **Scaling In**. Try to avoid using using terms such as *Scaling Up* and *Scaling Down* since they suggest that the instances are being made bigger and smaller (which is not the case).

**Scaling Out & In multiple times per hour**

The assumption in this statement is that such scaling is not desired, which is true. Amazon EC2 is charged per-hour, so adding instances and them removing them within a short period of time is wasting money. This is known as **thrashing**.

In general, it is a good idea to **Scale Out quickly and Scale In slowly**. When a system needs extra capacity (Scale Out), it will want it fairly quickly to satisfy demand. When it no longer needs as much capacity, it might be worthwhile waiting before Scaling In because demand might increase again very soon thereafter.

Therefore, it is important to get the right **alarm** to trigger a scaling action and to **wait** a while before trying to scale again.

**Optimize for cost while preserving elasticity**

When an exam question makes a statement about optimizing, it's giving you a hint that the primary goal should be cost minimization, even if other choices might make more sense. Therefore, you want the solution to **Scale In when possible, while avoiding thrashing**.

**Termination Policies**

When an Auto Scaling Policy is triggered to remove instances, Auto Scaling uses the [termination policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/as-instance-termination.html) to determine which instance(s) to remove. This is, therefore, irrelevant to the question because optimizing for cost while preserving elasticity is only impacted by the number of instances, not which instances are actually terminated.

**CloudWatch Alarms**

Auto Scaling actions can be triggered by CloudWatch alarms, such as *"average CPU < 70% for 15 minutes"*. A rule with a longer time period means that it will react to longer-term changes rather than temporary changes, which certainly helps avoid thrashing. However, it also means that Auto Scaling will **take longer to respond to changes in demand**.

**Cooldowns**

From the [Auto Scaling documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/Cooldown.html):

> The **Auto Scaling cooldown period** is a configurable setting for your Auto Scaling group that helps to ensure that Auto Scaling doesn't launch or terminate additional instances before the previous scaling activity takes effect. After the Auto Scaling group dynamically scales using a simple scaling policy, Auto Scaling **waits for the cooldown period to complete** before resuming scaling activities.

This is very useful, because newly-launched instances take some time (eg for booting, configuring) before they can take some of the application workload. If the cooldown is too **short**, then Auto Scaling might launch additional instances before the first one is ready. The result is that too many instances will be launched, meaning that some will need to Scale In soon after, leading to more thrashing.

**Scheduled Actions**

Instead of triggering Scale In and Scale Out actions based upon a metric, Auto Scaling can be configured to use Schedules actions. For example, increasing the **minimum** number of instances at 8am in the morning before an expected rush, and decreasing the minimum number at 6pm when usage starts to drop-off.

Scheduled Actions are unlikely to cause thrashing, since scaling is based on a schedule rather than metrics that frequently change.

**The Correct Answer**

The correct answer is... I'm not going to tell you! However, by reading the above information and trying to [grok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grok) how Auto Scaling works, you will hopefully come to a better understanding of the question and arrive at a suitable answer.

This way, you will have learned something rather than [merely memorizing the answers](http://dilbert.com/strip/2000-08-31).